# MySQL Query - Group or add production volume for a unit when the unit can produce two different products

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
widget (id, widget)
product(id, product, widget(fk))
production(id, date, widget(fk) units_made )
```

Each widget can produce 1 or more types of products.

What I am having trouble doing is creating a query to show me the TOTAL production for a widget.  So if widget A makes products X and Y, then I want to see the total production X and Y for widget A in terms of units made.

Below is an example of the data I currently see in my production table.

```
Date / Widget / Product / Units_Made
1-1-13 / A / X / 15
1-2-13 / A / Y / 30
1-3-13 / A / X / 8
1-1-13 / A / Y / 150
1-2-13 / A / X / 48
1-3-13 / A / Y / 7
```

How can I get the dates grouped so I can see the total production for Widget A?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? This will group dates, widgets and products no matter what category. You can further limit the query by adding a `HAVING` which is similar to `WHERE` except it is applied on groups (`WHERE` applies before `GROUP BY`).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/055d2/2

```
SELECT 
   Production.date, Widget.widget, Product.product, SUM(Production.units_made)
FROM
  ((Widget JOIN Production ON Widget.id = Production.widget) JOIN
    Product ON Production.product_id = Product.id)
GROUP BY
  Widget.widget, Product.product, Production.date
```

(See the SQLFiddle for a sample).